# Windows 10 Screen Resolution HP 2010 Series Monitor

Tags: windows-10, display-driver

My friend has an HP 2010 Series Wide LCD Monitor screen resolution problem with 
Windows 10. It seemed to be OK with Windows 7. Her screen is stretched. Everything is distorted.

Her screen seems to be the same size as mine, but mine is Philips brand.

We tried Uninstall driver with Device Manager, but that didn't work.

The problem seems to be with the driver, but I can't seem to find the right one.

My screen resolution is set at 1360 X 768, but that is not listed among the options for my friend's machine.

Comment: You never said what the problem is and what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the resolution your friend is currently set at? How many other resolution options? Graphics card?

Comment: Her screen is stretched. Everything is distorted. I don't know what her current resolution is. I currently have no access to her computer. There are only three resolutions. None work.